# how to remove fill under line from graph using angular-charts

Tags: angular-chart

I am fairly new to angular.  Trying to use angular-charts for some data visualization.  Charts.js lists an attribute "fill" for coloring below a line but I am not sure how to reference this in angular.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

In the latest version of angular-chart (1.X), chartjs 2.x is used. In this version, you need to use

```
$scope.options = {
    elements: {
        line: {
            fill: false
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found that I've made a huge mistake. The master branch of angular-chart is based on version 1.x of chart.js, but document on chartjs.org is for verion 2.x.

https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/v1.1.1/docs/01-Line-Chart.md

This is the correct line-chart option for angular-chart. So simply using

```
$scope.options = {
  datasetFill : false
}
```

is Ok.